# how to get <a> tag inner html in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript

I am just doing online shopping. I just want to get the  tag's inner html in asp.net c#. I tried a lot of examples. I tried through javascript also. But i cannot do it. Help me!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Are you trying to do this server-side or client side. Show your work so far, it will help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: use LinkButton control or give a runat attribute to your a tag.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to bind an ID to your anchor-tag and call it like so;

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" id="myAtag">Current text</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var a_tag_1 = document.getElementById('myAtag');

var a_tag_html = a_tag_1.innerHTML;
```

You "can" call all a-tags, but it's strongly recommended you narrow it down with either an ID or selecting the parent first and going down in there to find all a-tags. When you do so, you can use;

```
document.getElementsByTagName('a');
//or
my_var_element.getElementBytagName('a');
```

Comment: Close, though I think he wants to read the innerHtml, not set it. E.g. `var html = a_tag_1.innerHtml;` etc...